# C++ : Time taken in a for loop iteration

Tags: c++

Just as an experiment I have been running the following block of code. Where I estimate the time taken for different number of iterations in a `for` loop.

```
std::vector<double> numIt= {1e2, 1e4, 1e6, 1e8, 1e9, 1e10,1e11};
for(int i=0; i< (int) numIt.size() ; i++ )
{
    int tmp=0;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int j=0; j< numIt[i]; j++)
    {
        tmp=i-j;
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto durationFPextraction = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout <<i<< "\t"<< tmp<<"\t"<<numIt[i] << "\t" << durationFPextraction <<std::endl;
}
```

It prints the following, and has been running for a couple of hours now to iterate through `1e+10` length `for` loop. If the time taken is linear shouldn't it have taken ~14000 milliseconds (14 seconds) ?

`0  -99 100 0
1   -9998   10000   0
2   -999997 1e+06   2
3   -99999996   1e+08   144
4   -999999995  1e+09   1394`

Comment: What platform? Are you sure `1e11` is inside the range of your integers? And why compare an integer to a double?

Comment: Changed the inner for loop to 'long int' and it started working. It was an obvious case of integer overflow. My bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues.

1. Do not use c-style casts.
2. Do not use `int` for iterating over a `vector`, the type `size_t` is the correct one to use.
3. You are measuring something that is bellow measuring error threshold, therefore the numbers will always be unreliable.
4. For proper measurement use something like: https://github.com/google/benchmark it will make sure to run enough iterations to get statistical confidence.

Answer (score 1):

As David Schwartz comments, the sentence

> for (int j=0; j< numIt[i]; j++)

won't be appropriate because is likely to be a 32 bit value that will not be able to represent the 1e10 and 1e11 values from your numIt vector. When changing the code to use long long (64 bit values) it will continue looping.

```
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<double> numIt= {1e2, 1e4, 1e6, 1e8, 1e9, 1e10, 1e11};
    for(size_t i=0; i< numIt.size() ; i++ )
    {
        int tmp=0;
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (long long j=0; j< numIt[i]; j++)
        {
            tmp=i-j;
        }
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto durationFPextraction = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
        std::cout <<i<< "\t"<< tmp<<"\t"<<numIt[i] << "\t" << durationFPextraction <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

int is most likely 32 bit.

If that is a case then once your int reaches the value 2^31 - 1, increasing it by 1 produces undefined behaviour. In practice, the result of the undefined behaviour is often to set the int to the smallest possible value - (2^31). After another 2^32 iterations you are back at 2^31 - 1, then j changes to - (2^31) and so on forever and ever since j < 1e10 will always be true.

Your code will never finish running.